# Tomcat 7 Error renderResponse: /send-receive-updates

Tags: jsf, tomcat, tomcat7, icefaces, icefaces-1.8

I m getting error Problem in renderResponse: /send-receive-updates Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource.

Application was working fine in Jboss 4.2.3 now i m migrating it to tomcat 7 and icefaces version 1.8.2.

need your help for the same

jars which are in my project web inf are:

ant-1.5.1,
backport-util-concurrent,
bsf,
c3p0-0.9.1.2,
ch,
commons-beanutils,
commons-codec,
commons-collections,
commons-digester,
commons-el,
commons-fileupload,
commons-logging,
commons-net-1.3.0,
commons-pool-1.3,
dom4j-1.4,
el-ri,
hibernate3,
icefaces,
icefaces-comps,
icefaces-facelets,
iReport,
itext-1.3.1,
krysalis-jCharts-1.0.0-alpha-1,
servlet-api,
slf4j-api-1.5.0,
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0,
spring,
spring-mock,
xercesImpl,
xml-apis,
log4j-1.2.15,
jsf-api-1.2,
jsf-impl-1.2,
jstl.

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working?

Comment: hi simon....code is working in jboss thus it will also work in tomcat...the main issue is of jar....which i m not able to identify...thanks